# How to update local storage arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I am developing a shopping cart. The products in the cart are populated by this local storage array

```
{id: "1280-01-601-0179-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514502694923", name: "NRP CABLE ASSEMBLY", price: "$32",  quantity: "33"}

{id: "1660-01-519-2834-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514573672302", name: "SEPARATOR WATER,AIRCRAFT AIR CON", price: "$322",  quantity: "1"}

{id: "1510-01-312-3501-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514542566148", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$90",  quantity: "1"}
```

this is js code

```
var arrayLength = cartarry.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

var id = cartarry[i].id;

  var name = cartarry[i].name;
  var price = parseInt(cartarry[i].price.replace('$',""))
  var quantity = parseInt(cartarry[i].quantity);
  var linetotal = price * quantity;

     var itemcontainer = document.getElementById('myContent');
           // itemcontainer.innerHTML = '';
//Do something
  var itemcard = `
                    <div class="product" id="${id}">

                              <div class="product-details">
                                <div class="product-title">Dingo Dog Bones</div>
                                <p class="product-description"> ${name}</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="product-price" id='productprice'>${price}</div>
                              <div class="product-quantity">
                                <input type="number" id='productquantity' value=${quantity} min="1">
                              </div>
                              <div class="product-removal">
                                <button class="remove-product">
                                  Remove
                                </button>
                              </div>
                      <div class="product-line-price" id='productlineprice' >${linetotal}</div>
                      </div>

                              `
                    ;

                    itemcontainer.innerHTML += itemcard;
                    calculatelinetotal()


}
```

I want to recalculate the cart total price on quantity change. So updating the local storage array on quantity change and then recalculating to get the updated price and final cost. 
I was able to get the id of the changing quantity parent with this

```
$('.product-quantity input').change( function() {

 var id  = $(this).parents('.product')[0].id;

 });
```

so an example of

```
 console.log(id) // 1280-01-601-0179-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514502694923"
```

how can I update the quantity of the local storage array for a specific id and delete the array for a specific id?

Comment: Just store array of objects in local storage: [ { }, ..., { } ],
then you'll be able to add/remove/update any items like in normal array-like variable.

Answer (score 1):

In local storage you can only store strings. So the simplest thing to do is to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to store objects/arrays json encoded. Just rewrite the item completely.

Basically:

```
function updateArray (key, index, value) {
  var array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  array[idx] = value;
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(array));

}
```